# Drupal 8 get specific element in site path in twig template

Tags: drupal, twig

The current page url is http://website/p1/p2/p3/p4.
In Drupal 8 twig, use function to get path `p1/p2/p3/p4`

```
    {{ set site_path = path("<current>") }}
    {{ site_path }}
```

The site_path is `p1/p2/p3/p4`.
How to get the element in the path, for example, the second `p2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter **[split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html)**:

```
{% set parts = site_path|split('/') %}
{# now parts contains ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'] #}
{{ parts[1] }}
{# print 'p2' #}
```